# How do I add and read sqlite fields in Xcode 4 on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, xcode4

I want to add a sqlite database in my app and all tutorials says to add the files to the Resources folder. The issue is that i don't have a Resources folder in xCode 4. So is the a replacement for the folder? (I only need reed rights.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dragging your sqlite database file into the project navigation tree of your Xcode project should be enough to have it copied into your application in the build stage. It does not matter if your files are grouped under a common 'Resources' group or not.

That said, you can create groups by right clicking on the project navigation tree and selecting 'New Group'. It is common to have most application resources (sqlite dbs, images, etc) grouped together as a way to keep them organized and separate from source code, but it's not a requirement whatsoever.